# Маленькая правка скрипта JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть некая разметка и скрипт, который разворачивает и сворачивает контент.
Так вот, нужно чтобы разворачивалось или сворачивалось при клике только по родительским пунктам меню, а по внутренним был переход по ссылке, подскажите что исправить в скрипте.

```
<div class="view-source col-xs-6">
  <a href="#" class="p1">ПУНКТ МЕНЮ РОДИТЕЛЬСКИЙ <span>+</span></a>
  <div class="hides">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.view-source .hides').hide();
    $a = $('.view-source a');
    $a.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $a.not(this).next().slideUp(500);
      $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ` $('.p1').on('click',`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого достаточно изменить селектор:

```
$a = $('.view-source a');
```

На

```
$a = $('.view-source > a');
```

Демо:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.view-source .hides').hide();
  $a = $('.view-source > a');
  $a.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $a.not(this).next().slideUp(500);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-source col-xs-6">
  <a href="#" class="p1">ПУНКТ МЕНЮ РОДИТЕЛЬСКИЙ <span>+</span></a>
  <div class="hides">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/">МЕНЮ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!